# Swagger Authorization keys

Tags: javascript, swagger

In Swagger I have had problems to configure the authorizations.
In Available authorizations there are two fields to fill:

- subscription_key (apiKey)
  Provide your cognitive services subscription key here.
  Name: Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key
- token (apiKey)
  Provide an access token from the JWT returned by the STS of this region. Make sure to add the management scope to the token by adding the following query string to the STS URL: ?scope=speechservicesmanagement
   
  I did not find it clear where I have to get this info.
  Could someone help me?

Comment: Are you the developer of this API? Or is this someone else's API? If the latter, contact the API vendor for support.

Answer (score 1):

The two paramters can be found as follows:

**1. subscription_key parameter**: this can be found in Azure portal> Navigate to the Speech service that you must have created (Cognitive Service) or see [here to create new Speech service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started)  > use the value from Key1

Mine looks like below :
[image]

Things to remember :

- The speech to text api (especially conversational api) is supported only in specific regions, I chose centralus.
- The pricing tier should be S0 Standard to get the apis working (atleast for conversation apis)

**2. token (apiKey) parameter** :

- You will need to generate the token by sending a post request to the speech service endpoint (see image above for location of endpoint url).
- Add your subscription key as a header.
- The post request will generate the access token as response

Things to remember :

- As instructed in swagger, remember to add the query string of '?scope=speechservicesmanagement' to your endpoint url before generating the token.
  ex:  https://centralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken?scope=speechservicesmanagement